# Overridding a Shipping Method - What am I missing

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I've written many many modules before but for some reason my shipping module won't override an exsiting Magneto shipping method.  Is that allowed?  What am I missing here?  The module name shows up in the advanced tab of the configuration area, so it's getting loaded, but nothing is happening.  Any hints?

Code

etc/modules/Ssi_Shipping.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ssi_Shipping>
            <active>true</active>
            <codepool>local</codepool>
        </Ssi_Shipping>
    </modules>
</config>
```

local/Ssi/Shipping/etc.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Ssi_Shipping>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Ssi_Shipping>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <shipping>
        <rewrite>
          <carrier_tablerate>Ssi_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate</carrier_tablerate>
        </rewrite>
        
      </shipping>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

local/Ssi/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php

```php
<?php
class Ssi_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate 
  extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate {
      
      public function isActive()
      {
        Mage::log("here! Ssi_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate");
        
        // check to see if it's disabled
        if (parent::isActive() == false)
          return false;
        
        // check in the shopping cart
        foreach( Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item ){
          if ($item->getDeliveryFlag() == "test")
            return true;
      }

      // if nothing is found then disable this option.
        return false;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working through this one a bit, I found that the only way to override the shipping controller was to make a duplicate of the file (and directory structure) in the local code folder.  Then I could basically tweak the code.

Not sure why Magento doesn't seem to allow the standard overriding of these shipping functions, but a least there is a work around.

Comment: I strongly do not recommend this. There is a clean way to override the carrier, see my answer.

Answer (score 12):

There is a way but it is not obvious and required me to browse the shipping module source:

If you look at **Mage_Shipping_Model_Config**, you will discover that the code used as parameter for Mage::getModel() is taken from the store configuration. This code is NOT the standard code like 'shipping/carrier_tablerate', so it does not help overriding as usual.

Now you have to find out first what this code is. For example I wanted to override the matrixrate carrier, so I tested it like that:

```
$carrierConfig = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/matrixrate')
var_dump($carrierConfig['model']);
```

Yes, you can put this code anywhere on the page temporary but it is useful to have a separate file for such things that can be run from the command line (starting with Mage::app() to initialize Magento)

In my case the code was **matrixrate_shipping/carrier_matrixrate** so I had to change my config.xml like that:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <matrixrate_shipping>
            <rewrite>
                <carrier_matrixrate>my_class_name</carrier_matrixrate>
            </rewrite>
        </matrixrate_shipping>
    </models>
```

instead of

```
<global>
    <models>
        <matrixrate>
            <rewrite>
                <carrier_matrixrate>my_class_name</carrier_matrixrate>
            </rewrite>
        </matrixrate>
    </models>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: mate, thank you for this one, it has been giving me a headache for some time

Answer (score 1):

Check first that the model is being overridden at all. Try this:

```
var_dump(get_class(Mage::getModel("shipping/carrier_tablerate")));
```

Comment: Where would I put that?  Anywhere on the page?

Comment: I keep a file around that initializes the framework but gives me a "scratchboard" (a nearly cloned version of the index.php file) To be quick, you should be able to put it into a template, for instance, and be fine. Just remember to remove it later.

Answer (score 0):

it's been a while but I had the same problem the last days. I wanted to override freeshipping and flatrate shipping methods and in addition to the answer of fab I had to add the following code in etc/config.xml. In my case the original values are located in app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/etc/config.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    ...
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <flatrate>
                <model>your_module/shipping_carrier_flatrate</model>
            </flatrate>
            <freeshipping>
                <model>your_module/shipping_carrier_freeshipping</model>
            </freeshipping>
        </carriers>
    </default>
</config>
```

The model values are examples. You have to replace them with your correct paths.

Comment: Can you please share what's inside shipping_carrier_flatrate class

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is facing this problem and came here for solution, it looks like OP have used `codepool` in module file where it should be `codePool` (notice the capital P).